# Why do I have a mpicc installation error?

Tags: c, linux, mpi

Hi I am trying to use an mpi program. To compile it, I need mpi compiler but when I am installing it I have an error.

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin openmpi-common libopenmpi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ibverbs-providers libfabric1 libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5
  libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libnl-route-3-200 libnuma-dev libnuma1
  libopenmpi3 libpmix2 libpsm-infinipath1 libpsm2-2 librdmacm1
  ocl-icd-libopencl1
Suggested packages:
  libhwloc-contrib-plugins openmpi-doc opencl-icd
Recommended packages:
  libcoarrays-openmpi-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ibverbs-providers libfabric1 libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5
  libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libnl-route-3-200 libnuma-dev libopenmpi-dev
  libopenmpi3 libpmix2 libpsm-infinipath1 libpsm2-2 librdmacm1
  ocl-icd-libopencl1 openmpi-bin openmpi-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnuma1
1 upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 252 not upgraded.
Need to get 5 271 kB/5 624 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 libnuma1 amd64 2.0.11-2.2ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
...
```

Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseNotes

> Ubuntu 18.10 was supported for 9 months until July 2019. If you need
>   Long Term Support, it is recommended you use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS instead.

Your best bet is to upgrade to a newer distro (or downgrade to 18.04).
You might also be able to find some mirrors and use them to install the missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your sources.list and use a different mirror.

As [described in this post](http://vinyll.scopyleft.fr/upgrade-ubuntu-cosmic/), you should replace in your */etc/apt/sources.list* all urls with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/…` by `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/…`.
Then you run `sudo apt update`, and you can install your packages again.

Note that you really should consider to upgrade while it's still not too much of a pain.